# How do you look for and copy files if they exist in other profiles with applescript?

Tags: applescript, duplicates, repeat, paragraphs

I am trying to create an applescript to look in each users profile for crash logs in ~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports  .. I use the * at the end because there could be .crash .spin .hang files and I need to copy them all to the current desktop into the folder "Test" but am not sure if that was the proper way to do it.

When I try and run it I get

> error "Can’t make \"Test.txt\" into type integer." number -1700 from
>   "Test.txt" to integer

```
try
    do shell script "ls /users >$HOME/Desktop/Users.txt"
    do shell script "mkdir ~/Desktop/Test"
end try

set b to boot volume of (system info)
set u to b & "Users"

set theFiles to paragraphs of "Test.txt"



repeat theFiles times
duplicate file u & theFiles & "~/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/Xxxxx*" to "~/Desktop/Test"

end repeat
```

Thanks all for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use do shell script:

```
do shell script "mkdir -p ~/Desktop/Test
cp /Users/*/Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/* ~/Desktop/Test" with administrator privileges
```

Or loop through `folders of (path to users folder)`:

```
tell application "Finder"
    if exists folder "Test" of desktop then
        set d to folder "Test" of desktop
    else
        set d to make new folder at desktop with properties {name:"Test"}
    end if
    repeat with f in (get folders of (path to users folder))
        tell contents of f
            if exists folder "DiagnosticReports" of folder "Logs" of folder "Library" then
                duplicate items of folder "DiagnosticReports" of folder "Logs" of folder "Library" to d
            end if
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell
```

If you don't have permissions to read the files of other users, you can run Finder as root with `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.Finder.plist; sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/Finder.app/Contents/MacOS/Finder`.

Comment: HI thanks but both scripts seem to only get the logs from the current user, I put a crash log on another user for testing and it didn't copy it.

Comment: If you need root privileges, add `with administrator privileges` or run Finder as root.

Comment: Sorry but how would you go about setting that up ?